# HTML and Typography - Acute Accent (+0301), Cyrillic , and HTML

Tags: html, css, typography

I am building an App for working with Russian linguistic data. It's a web-app (MongoDB + Node).

I'm having the following problem: I use the [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) to indicate a stressed vowel. For some reason, this looks strange when rendered by my browser.

Here is how the text is rendered in my browser (Chrome):

[image]

As you can see, it seems as though the letters of each word containing an accent are larger after the accent (ie. существу**ЮТ**). I have this issue specifically when using the font PT Serif, which I particularly like for displaying the cyrillic alphabet.

CSS:

```
#TextContainer {
  font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

Why does this happen with this font? Is it possible to fix this using CSS or do I have to use a different font?

Comment: Is the accented o in the cyrillic alphabet you are using?

Comment: yes - it's the [Cyrillic O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_(Cyrillic))

Comment: I mean does the cyrillic font you use have an accented cyrillic o or are you using a non-cyrillic font for it?

Comment: The accent is a diacritic, ie it's a separate character. The font is [PT Serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PT_Fonts), so made for Cyrillic characters. The acute accent is quite commonly used in Russian although it's not technically a Cyrillic character.

Comment: I just realized that it seems to be connected to Serif vs. Sans... it displays normally with any Sans fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out myself so here it is for posterity:

It's not an issue with this particular font, it seems to be related to Sans fonts vs Sans Serif fonts - Sans Serif fonts display the accents properly, whereas Serif fonts don't. I just didn't test a wide enough variety of fonts. Will use "PT Sans" instead of "PT Serif".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the font-size try using this

```
  font-family: Sans-Serif, 10px; 
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
```